# WATIN and multitabbed IE

Tags: internet-explorer-7, watin, tabbed

I have a WATIN test like the following:

```
[Test]
public void IE_should_launch_on_correct_url()
{
  // do something here that should launch IE
  ...
  _ie = IE.AttachToIE(Find.ByUrl(someUrl));
  ...
  Assert.IsNotNull(_ie);
}

[TearDown]
public void Tidy()
{ 
  _ie.Close();
}
```

If there's another IE (7) opened, the first line of the test opens a new tab on that IE and then the last one asserts there's an IE with that url opened. Now, when the `Tidy` method executes, it closes the first tab opened in IE, not the one the test opened. 
How can I avoid that? Is there any way I can close an arbitrary tab with WATIN?

Thanks in advance